# how do I prevent elements to move, when I increase the font size of an element when hovering?

Tags: html, css

I want to increase the font size of .navbar span when hovering, which works perfectly fine, but the elements around it move with the increased font size. How do I prevent this?

```css
.navbar {
    padding: 15px;
    margin: -8px;
    border: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 95%, 0.5);
}

.navbar span {
    margin: 70px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.navbar span:hover {
    font-size :20px;
}
```

```html
   <body>
      <header>
        <nav>
            <div class="navbar">
                <span>Startseite</span>
                <span>Speisekarte</span>
                <span>Kontakt</span>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <h1 class="main_header">Julio's Pizza</h1>
      </header>
   <body/>
```

Comment: @ATP yeah I made a mistake and edited it. The "transform" wasn't supposed to be there

Answer (score 0):

Allocate the elements enough space so that they don't overflow.  Try to allocate a fixed amount of `px` for each of the `span`s inside of the `.navbar`:

```css
.navbar > span {
  width: [x]px;
  height: [y]px;
}
```

or set the dimensions of the `.navbar` itself to some fixed number of `px` or `rem`.

Be sure to handle the mobile scaling as well and the common approach is to start with mobile devices and apply breakpoints as the screen size increases.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is not use any paddings, but instead define the height of your navbar and use flex to position your `<span>` elements. Something like this:

```css
.navbar {
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid hsla(0, 0%, 95%, 0.5);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar span {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: 0.3s;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}

.navbar span:hover {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="navbar">
    <span>Startseite</span>
    <span>Speisekarte</span>
    <span>Kontakt</span>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach is simply increase the element's `scale`:

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  /* setting the default font-size for all elements: */
  font-size: 16px;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 15px;
  margin: -8px;
  /* changed the colour to the updated/current version
     of whitespace-separated hue, saturation and light
     and the alpha following the '/' character: */
  border: 1px solid hsl(0 0% 95% / 0.5);
}

.navbar span {
  /* in order to allow transform to be used effectively: */
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 70px;
  font-weight: 600;
  /* setting the default scale to 1: */
  transform: scale(1);
  /* setting up the transition, to affect the 'transform'
     property-values, over 0.3 seconds with the ease-in
     transition timing: */
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
}

.navbar span:hover {
  /* using a large scale to make the transition/increase
     more obvious, but adjust to your own preference: */
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

h1 {
  /* because I set all font-sizing on the page to 16px
     here we update the <h1> element(s) to have a font-
     size to be twice the root-em size: */
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="navbar">
      <span>Startseite</span>
      <span>Speisekarte</span>
      <span>Kontakt</span>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <h1 class="main_header">Julio's Pizza</h1>
</header>
```

I've used `transition` to cause the change in `transform` to animate between the 'normal' and 'hover' states.

I would, however, recommend a slightly revised approach to your HTML, for example:

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  /* explicitly setting the browser to the same layout/sizing calculations
     for all elements; this includes padding and border-width in the assigned
     height/width settings: */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* setting the default font-size for all elements: */
  font-size: 16px;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

h1 {
  /* because I set all font-sizing on the page to 16px
     here we update the <h1> element(s) to have a font-
     size to be twice the root-em size: */
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 15px;
  /* changed the colour to the updated/current version
     of whitespace-separated hue, saturation and light
     and the alpha following the '/' character: */
  border: 1px solid hsl(0 0% 95% / 0.5);
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.navbar li {
  font-weight: 600;
  /* setting the default scale to 1: */
  transform: scale(1);
  /* setting up the transition, to affect the 'transform'
     property-values, over 0.3 seconds with the ease-in
     transition timing: */
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in;
}

.navbar li:hover {
  /* using a large scale to make the transition/increase
     more obvious, but adjust to your own preference: */
  transform: scale(1.5);
}

li:first-child {
  transform-origin: left center;
}

li:last-child {
  transform-origin: right center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <!-- the <h1> content is, arguably, among the most important content on the page,
       therefore I feel it should come first in the markup; if the <h1> should appear
       visually after the navbar content then we can (as I have here) use "display: flex"
       and use "flex-direction: column-reverse" to have it appear as you wish: -->
  <h1 class="main_header">Julio's Pizza</h1>
  <nav>
    <!-- the navigation is, conceptually, a list of links in a particular order; so
         I follow the trend/custom of using an <ol> for these links; though you've
         not used <a> elements to wrap those links/titles, so I just changed the
         <span> elements to <li> elements without an enclosed <a> element: -->
    <ol class="navbar">
      <li>Startseite</li>
      <li>Speisekarte</li>
      <li>Kontakt</li>
    </ol>
  </nav>
</header>
```